# Django 1.11 authentication set_unusable_password vs setting password to None

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-authentication

My team has overwritten the authenticate method for users years ago to authenticate against LDAP instead of djangos model backend.

this method looks at LDAP for the user. If the user exists with correct username and password, it gets or creates the user (This means that the user doesn't have to exist as a model object in the Django database for someone to log in).

The method leaves the newly created password as None. Then sets all the other information.

I noticed that they, after validating the user, call the set_unusable_password on the user if they were valid. In a comment, they wrote that it overrides Django's built-in password handling... which obviously that makes sense. But I don't know why they needed to since we've already overwritten the authenticate method.

I tested this out by removing the set_unusable_password so that the password is left as None and the validation worked. They were still able to log in with the password that's stored on LDAP. You still could not overwrite the password in the model to be different than that on LDAP and login with that.

So basically the set_unusable_password call had no effect other than just creating a password... which wasn't used anyways.

the only thing I can think of is that it may be a solution to an issue that was in older versions of Django (we're now in 1.11).

After spending much time in the source code and in documentation, I couldn't figure out why we need it.

Why would that be there? The people that wrote it have left by now so I have no explanation for why they did it. If I remove that, would there be any unwanted side effects?

Answer (score 7):

Your code may work if you set the password to `None` but it's good practice to use `set_unusable_password`.

Users with an unusable password [are not allowed to request a password reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView). If you had the `ModelBackend` and LDAP backends enabled, then a user with `password=None` could reset their password and then log in with the model backend.

Comment: I tested it with that. You can change the password in the ModelBackend but the authenticate overwrite that we wrote ignores it. So the new password will be ignored and the LDAP password will still be used. So I guess in that case, it only serves for clarity sake?

Comment: Yes, calling `set_unusable_password` is clearer than setting it to `None`, I can go look up what that API means in the docs. It also prevents users from being able to reset their password and then log in if your settings change in future.